# Following Records

Tags: database, delphi, loops, records

I've been having a little problem with getting my program to follow records through a database dependent on the values within the record, simply put, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

This is a simplified version of the table I'm working with:

```
Record Name  |  Val1  | Val2  | Link |  Prev Link |
Rec1         |   5    |  3    | Rec2 |            |
Rec2         |   2    |  4    | Rec6 |  Rec1      |
Rec3         |   1    |  8    | Rec4 |            |
Rec4         |   1    |  1    |      |  Rec3      |
Rec5         |   8    |  3    |      |            |
Rec6         |   9    |  3    |      |  Rec2      |
```

My program needs to go through the above table, save the information against one particular record, go to it's linked record, clear the values of the previous record and then add them onto the newer record (it should keep doing this till it reaches the end of the chain), as an example here is what should happen after running my program.

```
Record Name  |  Val1  | Val2  | Link |  Prev Link |
Rec1         |   0    |  0    | Rec2 |            |
Rec2         |   0    |  0    | Rec6 |  Rec1      |
Rec3         |   0    |  0    | Rec4 |            |
Rec4         |   2    |  9    |      |  Rec3      |
Rec5         |   8    |  3    |      |            |
Rec6         |   16   |  10   |      |  Rec2      |
```

The current procedure I am using can be found at the following location: http://pastebin.com/A10hW0C6

The main problem I am facing is that I cannot get the program to go through each record, follow any links and then return to the place that it left off to make sure it doesn't miss any, also how can I make the program ignore records that it has already been over as part of a loop?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Please post your code here. Having to leave this site to go elsewhere to read it is annoying, and it's not available if the external site is moved or is off-line for some reason. It also isn't searchable by future readers. Post the smallest portion of it that applies to your question here, please. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you're actually iterating the table.. you need to have tblParts.first before your while loop and tblParts.next at the bottom of your while loop.

Comment: *lvBookmark := tblParts.RecNo* - why that ? Standard way, so better supported by library, would be *lvBookmark := tblParts.Bookmark*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you can do is to have a seperate query to hold the start-of-the-link records, such as:

```
qry1.sql := 'select * from table where prev_link is null;';
```

This gives

```
Record Name  |  Val1  | Val2  | Link |  Prev Link |       
Rec1         |   5    |  3    | Rec2 |            |       
Rec3         |   1    |  8    | Rec4 |            |       
Rec5         |   8    |  3    |      |            |
```

Then you can follow the result data set, seek/locate on the other query (query2), and apply your processing logic there.

By the time you finished with the result date set, you are done. This, of course, assuming that your data is legit, i.e. no broken links, no circular links, etc.

Some enhancement. You can add a column called 'status' to reflect the status of the record. For example, status = 0 means 'Unprocessed', '1' means processed, '2' means broken links, '3' means circular link, etc. You can start by populating all status column with 0 (unprocessed).

If you can not find the record by seeking/locating it in the 'Link' column (maybe somehow get deleted), then you can flag the status to '2'.

Each time you follow a link, keep a track of the followed record. You can use a list, for example. Before following a record in the 'Link' column, check the list. If the record is in the list, then you have a circular link. Stop following, mark the status to '3' (circular link), clear the list, and start with the next record in query1. Dealing with circular link is important, otherwise your program can stuck on it (never ended).

When you finish processing a chain of links, then flag status to '1' to all records in the list.

You can make use of database transaction (begin transaction ...end transaction), so when you encounter deadlink or circular link down the link-chain, you can rollback the changed values, and flag the status accordingly.

After you finish, you can check the status column. If all '1' means all good (processed). If not then you can decide what to do next.

The column status can be used to filtered out already processed records on another sub sequent operations, so the query above can be altered:

```
qry1.sql := 'select * from table where prev_link is null and status = 0;';
```

Of course this is a preliminary strategy, and you can modify it to suit you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you're using, this could be solved purely by SQL on the server. Here's an example for Firebird (assuming the links are consistent and there is no infinite recursion which could be enforced by referential integrity constraints and triggers - these are not included here).

```
/* metadata */
set sql dialect 3;

create table test (
    id       integer not null,
    val1     integer,
    val2     integer,
    next_id  integer,
    prev_id  integer
);

alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id);
alter table test add constraint fk_test_next_id foreign key (next_id) references test (id) on update cascade;
alter table test add constraint fk_test_prev_id foreign key (prev_id) references test (id) on update cascade;

/* data */
insert into test (id, val1, val2, next_id, prev_id) values (1, 5, 3, 2, null);
insert into test (id, val1, val2, next_id, prev_id) values (2, 2, 4, 6, 1);
insert into test (id, val1, val2, next_id, prev_id) values (3, 1, 8, 4, null);
insert into test (id, val1, val2, next_id, prev_id) values (4, 1, 1, null, 3);
insert into test (id, val1, val2, next_id, prev_id) values (5, 8, 3, null, null);
insert into test (id, val1, val2, next_id, prev_id) values (6, 9, 3, null, 2);

/* update statement (could also be a stored procedure) */
execute block
as
  declare variable id integer;
  declare variable val1 integer;
  declare variable val2 integer;
begin
  for with recursive test_list (
    id,
    val1,
    val2,
    next_id
  )
  as (
    select
      t.id,
      t.val1,
      t.val2,
      t.next_id
    from test t
    where (t.prev_id is null)
    union all
    select
      t.id,
      t.val1 + tl.val1,
      t.val2 + tl.val2,
      t.next_id
    from test t
    join test_list tl on (tl.id = t.prev_id)
  )
  select
    tl.id,
    iif(tl.next_id is null, tl.val1, 0) val1,
    iif(tl.next_id is null,  tl.val2, 0) val2
  from test_list tl
  order by tl.id
  into
    :id, 
    :val1,
    :val2
  do
    update test set
      val1 = :val1,
      val2 = :val2
    where (id = :id);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

TOndrej gave you very good answer, but u need to know SQL well for that.
It pays - making correct SQL would make your database reliable, errors in ur program would not corrupt database data. But you would have a time to learn.
Also his SQL uses function of rather recent Firebird versions, word hardly apply to NexusDB or other servers.

Here is a more dumb approach. You may try it as well.

So, if i understand your task, the table is split into set of chains ?
Here u have three chains : *Rec1->Rec2->Rec6* and *Rec3->Rec4* and *Rec5* alone.

When u add new element, it **always** goes to tail, so it will be *Rec1->Rec2->Rec6->NewRec7*, but **never** can be *NewRec7->Rec1->Rec2->Rec6* nor *Rec1->Rec2->NewRec7->Rec6*.

Is it all so ?

Then u can add column distance-from-root

```
Record Name  |  Val1  | Val2  | Link |  Prev Link | Dist |
Rec1         |   5    |  3    | Rec2 |            |  0   |
Rec2         |   2    |  4    | Rec6 |  Rec1      |  1   |  
Rec3         |   1    |  8    | Rec4 |            |  0   |  
Rec4         |   1    |  1    |      |  Rec3      |  1   |  
Rec5         |   8    |  3    |      |            |      |  
Rec6         |   9    |  3    |      |  Rec2      |  2   |
```

You may calculate and update it in SQL triggers or in your programs.
SQL triggers are better - more reliable. But u would need to grasp them.
**Anytime when you will add record, delete record, or change record links - yow would have to re-calculate distances for all affected records. For example, if i take Rec6, cut and reconnect it into Rec1->Rec2, Rec6->Rec3->Rec4, then distances for Rec6 and Rec3 and Rec4 would have to be re-calculated**

1) get max(dist) from database.

> SELECT MAX(DIST) FROM THE_TABLE

2) for every chosen_dist from 0 to max(dist)-1

2.1) for every record with such a distance

> SELECT RecordName, Link, Val1, Val2  FROM THE_TABLE WHERE dist = :choosen_dist AND Link IS NOT NULL

2.1.1) update the next linked one incrementing the values

> UPDATE THE-TABLE SET Val1 = Val1 + :PrevLinked_Val1; Val2 = Val2 + :PrevLinked_Val2 WHERE RecordName = :NextLink

2.1.2) update the chosen one, clearing the values

> UPDATE THE-TABLE SET Val1 = 0; Val2 = 0 WHERE RecordName = :CurrentRecordName

This approach is worse:

1. not so fast - many separate statements repeated instead of bundled into one procedure and called once;
2. not so fast and less reliable - if you would call it from program one line after another, then data would be flying over network from server to program and back, instead of all calculations inside the server
3. you would have to be **very careful** when calculating distances. Up to the point of deleting them **ALL** and re-calculating if something got broken.

Also it is better:

1. easier to understand for SQL novices
2. only uses very basic SQL, so can go into any server: NexusDB, Firebird, SQLite, whatever u choose